# Zipfile library extraction issue

Tags: python

I'm using http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html to compress file into a zip. It works well but when extracting that file via my ubuntu (not in python, just right clicking file and then 'Extract here') file is truncated. My original file has ~167kb, extracted via ubuntu ~164kb (it's csv file, so I miss few lines from the end of file).

Any suggestions?

Edit:

My code looks as follows:

```
try:
    fp2 = zipfile.ZipFile(el.replace('.csv', '.zip'), 'w',
            zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    fp2.testzip()
    fp2.write(el)
finally:
    fp2.close()
```

Where el is some csv file.

Edit2:
It appears that while writing to a zipfile some data is lost.

Comment: Are you sure you closed the file?  (If you don't call close the documentation warns that some essential records can be left out)

Comment: maybe try 'wb' instead of 'w' for mode?

Comment: I'm linux user. So when I put 'wb' in place of 'w', I receive RuntimeError.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions:

(1) You call `testzip` but ignore the returned value. It may mess things up if the archive is empty (as it is in this case). Remove the call to `testzip`.

(2) Test the integrity of the created file by another means e.g. (a) `linux_zipfile_executable -t your_created_archive.zip` (b) short Python script using `testzip`. Try some other extraction means.

(3) Ignore the `mode='wb'` pushers; that is relevant only to files opened with built-in `open`. As the zipfile docs say, the only permissible modes are `r`, `w`, and `a`. Else: `RuntimeError: ZipFile() requires mode "r", "w", or "a"`. The zipfile code actually does use the `b` flag when it opens the archive file using built-in `open`.

(4) Check carefully that in the flurry of trying to find your problem you are in fact comparing the correct pair of csv files.

(5) Post the 3 files (input, output, and .zip) on the web somewhere.

Comment: The truth is, that it wasn't issue with zipfile, it was an issue with csv and it's writer. I was making some operation on freshly generated csv file, without closing file pointer that was passed to csv.writer. Closing it before doing actual compression solved mine problem.